# how to use AuthGuard correctly

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an angular application where I want to use authguard to protect some routes but for some reason it does not work. I first make a post request to my spring boot backend, if that gives me success I set a value to true and check that value in my canActivate methode. But it does not work, it does not even go into that method. I thought it is called automatically if I set it in my path in app-route.module. How can I use it correctly?

Authenticationservice with authguard together:

```
export class AuthenticationService {




  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private router: Router,

  ) { }

  authenticateUser(login: LoginModel){
    return this.http.post(environment.rootUrl + 'authenticate', {
      username: login.username,
      password: login.password,
    }).subscribe({
      next: (data) => {
       localStorage.setItem('token', data.toString())
      }, error: (error) => {
        this.isAuthenticated = false
      }
    })
  }

  isUserLoggedIn(){
    return !!localStorage.getItem('token')
  }

  
}
```

Authguard:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(
    private auth: AuthenticationService,
    private router: Router
  ) {
  }

  canActivate(): Promise<boolean> {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      if (this.auth.isUserLoggedIn()) {
        resolve(true)
      } else {
        this.router.navigate(['authenticate'])
        resolve(false)
      }
    })
  }
}
```

App-module:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, NxWelcomeComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    NbLayoutModule,
    LoginComponentModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NbThemeModule.forRoot({ name: 'default' }),
    NbLayoutModule,
    NbEvaIconsModule,
  ],
  providers: [AuthGuard],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

App-routing-module:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'dashboard' , component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  {path: 'authenticate', component: LoginComponent},
  {path: '' , redirectTo: 'authenticate', pathMatch: 'full'}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: [AuthGuard]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {

}
```

Comment: You are not using it within `canActivate`

Comment: They also must have `@Injectable()` attached to the class.

Comment: How can I use it? I thought if I put into my routes it will automatically look at it

Comment: You only have `AuthenticationService`, you need both something like this: `canActivate: [AuthGuard, AuthenticationService]` (order may/may not matter depending on your application).

Comment: I had already injectable it still did not work, I just did not have copied it here. I read somewhere I have to add it in providers in AppModule and I did it. But still not working

Comment: I seperated those two into different classes, do I still have to do it? I mean add it to canActivate

Comment: remove `implements CanActivate` from `AuthenticationService` and you need to call `authenticateUser` in your `AuthGuard`

Comment: But how would I enter the values? LoginModel? that was the reason with the isUserLoggedIn method which should return true if the token is saved in case of correct login.

Comment: I wouldn't do the login using a Guard. Put it in a service and when they click the login button call the login from the service. Use the Guard to only check if they are logged in and not make the actual login

Comment: That was how I thought it would work. I have a method which makes a post request. if it is successful it saves the jwt token inside the localstorage. Then I have a method (isUserLoggedIn) which returns true if the token is saved inside the localStorage. The canActivate checks the method which returns true depending on token. I added app module and updated app-routing module

Comment: What I noticed is if I set a breakpoint it does not land in AuthGuard at all

Comment: Could you please make a reproduceable example on https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-t4yqsp?file=src/app/app.component.ts
Here is a stackblitz, i tried to make a really basic structure

Answer (score 1):

You need to route to the dashboard after you do the login:

The routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  },
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'authenticate', pathMatch: 'full' },
];
```

The Component:

```
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(
    private authService: AuthenticationService,
    private router: Router
  ) {}

  callServiceMethod(value: string) {
    // This will need to wait for auth to finish before navigating in the actual app.
    this.authService.authenticateUser(value);
    if (this.authService.isAuthenticated) {
      this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
    }
  }
}
```

The Guard:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private auth: AuthenticationService, private router: Router) {}

  canActivate(): Promise<boolean> {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      console.log('running auth guard!');
      if (this.auth.isUserLoggedIn()) {
        resolve(true);
      } else {
        this.router.navigate(['authenticate']);
        resolve(false);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Here is an updated example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-5excpc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: But then what about the authguard does it still check? In this form do I even need an authguard? Because doesnt the service method deal with everything?

Comment: The authguard will only run when you hit the route that it is attached to.

Comment: The url change did work thanks but I have two questions, first can I make my authguard redirect to a page if the user for example enters wrong credentials? And secondly the url changed but the website did not navigate

Comment: yeah, you can return `this.router.navigate(['some', 'path']);` in your `canActivate()`

Comment: thanks for the answer, do you have any idea why my component is not being displayed even though the url is changing`?

Comment: do you have a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in your `app.component.html`?

Comment: I tried routeroutlet, but it is rendering the component beneath it. And on initial loading renders my login component two times

Comment: You should probably open a new question for this, as it isn't related to the AuthGuard.

Answer (score 0):

Your canActivate should only take your AuthGuard class which has the resolver.

```
{path: 'dashboard' , component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]}
```

Comment: Hi, I edited my code app-routing.module is updated only AuthGUard is inside but it still does not work. I do not get any error messages or something like that either...